# DynamoDB PartiQL Request Parameter In Select

Tags: select, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, partiql

I am attempting to use PartiQL to query a set of data that looks like this:

```
{
  "userId": {
    "S": "someuserID"
  },
  "mapWithData": {
    "M": {
      "1": {
        "M": {
          "neededVal": {
            "S": "A Needed Value1"
          },
          "name": {
            "S": "A Name1"
          }
        }
      },
      "2": {
        "M": {
          "neededVal": {
            "S": ""A Needed Value12"
          },
          "name": {
            "S": "A Name2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "userName": {
    "S": "someuserName"
  }
}
```

I am developing this query using the [NoSQL Workbench](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/workbench.html). I want to use a Request Parameter in the query to get a specific object from the `mapWithData` based on its key value. For instance, if I wanted to get the n-th value from the map, I could use this query:

```
SELECT "mapWithData"."N"."neededVal"
FROM "some-table"
WHERE "userId" = 'someuserID'
```

But I would like to be able to make the `"N"` and the `'someruserID'` into Request Parameters to prevent any PartiQL injections (assuming the Request Parameters are actually cleansed). So what I'm trying to do is this:

```
SELECT "mapWithData".?."neededVal"
FROM "some-table"
WHERE "userId" = ?
```

This does not work unfortunately and I get this error:

> Execute PartiQL statement failed: Validation Error: Statement wasn't well formed, can't be processed: Invalid path dot component

So then I tried to use a different format like this:

```
SELECT "mapWithData"[ ? ]["neededVal"]
FROM "some-table"
WHERE "userId" = ?
```

But when I do that, I get this error:

> Execute PartiQL statement failed: Validation Error: Unexpected path component at 1:23:1

Is it possible to include a `?` for inserting request parameters in the `SELECT` part of this statement? Is there another way to do this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

@Francis, sure you can do that: if you use the PythonSDK to implement it you can write:

```
table_name = 'mytable'
someruserID = 

stmt = f"SELECT * FROM {table_name} WHERE userId=?"
pmt =[{
   "S": userId
 }]

resp = dynamodb.execute_statement(
Statement=stmt , Parameters= pmt
)
```

Hope that helps. A

Comment: In my code I ended up doing something like this with hand-written sanitation, but my question was specifically about using the [NoSQL Workbench for DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/workbench.html). It seems as though it is not possible to do this in the NoSQL Workbench. The table name must be hardcoded in there.